# ember-cli watch file changes in subdirectories of the styles folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I started using EmberJS and ember-cli for a new project. Therefore I created a new project with ember-cli and added broccoli-compass with sass support. When I execute "ember server" in the terminal, ember is just watching for file changes on /app/styles/app.scss. I want ember-cli to also reload on file changes in subdirectories of the /app/styles folder (e.g. /app/styles/helpers/breakpoints.scss). How can I configure ember-cli for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried making a helpers directory and watchme.scss, and it sucessfully watches for changes, I suggest update your ember-cli version via `npm update ember-cli`. Here's the output:

```
file changed styles/helpers/watchme.scss
Build successful - 157ms.
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already using the newest ember-cli version, so I reinstalled it. Now it's working.